# www gets added to url address in codeigniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, url-rewriting, ip-address

I have a problem with my code igniter site. 
I am migrating it from one server to another, but before doing so, i need to set up a copy of the original site on the new server, and in order to test it, i need to use 
IP addresses as url's since DNS doesnt point to that server yet.
e.g http://xxx.yyy.aaa.xxx/controller/action

however, codeigniter ... or something keeps adding www to the url, which makes it fail the dns lookup.

If i try to access web resources that are "outside" of codeigniter, like
http://xxx.yyy.aaa.xxx/testdir/testfile.php
then it works and i can see the file.

How do i stop codeigniter from adding www to url's ?

Comment: have you added a value for base_url in application/config/config.php ?

Comment: as @cartalot said, check the base_url config + have a look if you .htaccess file in the docroot is set up to force the www